# Check if a proccess is running every 20 seconds and kill him on OSX

Tags: python, bash, macos, storyboard, xcode8

Currently, I have some issue with Xcode and the proccess **IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch** freeze Xcode each time I edit Storyboard.

So, I want to kill this proccess with a bash or python script by checking every x seconds if this proccess is running.

I think I can use this script, but how to do with a timer ( each x seconds checking ? )

```
pid=$(ps -fe | grep 'IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch' | awk '{print $2}')
if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
    kill $pid
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a while loop,

```
while sleep 20; do
    pid=$(ps -fe | grep 'IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch' | awk '{print $2}')
    if [[ -n $pid ]]; then
        kill $pid
    else
        echo "Does not exist"
    fi
done
```

The syntax `while sleep 20; do <code>` is similar to the one showed in comments `while true; do sleep 20 <code>`, except saving a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **If the process is named IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch**:

```
kill $(pgrep -x IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch)
```

If the process exists it will get killed, if not nothing will happen.

`pgrep` will get PID for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 20; do
    kill $(pgrep IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch)
done
```

If you dont want to use sleep, You can use `cron`.

Comment: From the question, you can't tell whether `IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch` is a program name or an argument to the program, so you can't use `pgrep`

Comment: @arco444 **proccess IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch** hard to understand?

Comment: @Inian Funny that we have an answer saying use sleep, and I got the downvote :D lauging irl.

Comment: The point suggested by arco444 is valid, and it is not related to how you used the `sleep`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make it sleep for 20 seconds?

```bash
sleep 20
```